# How does one know that how many births he/she is yet to take? And is his/her present level of conciousness?

Tags: atma, rebirth

As per the book *Immortal talks*, every soul has a level like T12 or T13; T14 being the highest. How do we know which level soul are we?

Comment: What is the correct name of the book? "Immortal souls" or something else?

Comment: @Rickross I think must be immortal yogi book!!!!

Comment: It is Immortal talks by Shunya

Comment: "How does one know that how many births he/she is yet to take?" you cannot know this. Maybe if you can consult a rishi who can see the future.

" And is his/her present level of conciousness?"
Will always remains unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can chose for this one to be your last birth. For that, you need to meditate. Once your *Kundalini* (Also known as *Parashakti* or the divine coiled energy) starts rising and all of your seven Chakras open, you will achieve enlightenment. Then, it will be the end of desires and thus end of re-birth.

> He who knows the Supreme Brahman verily becomes Brahman. (Mundaka Upanishad 3.2.9) Brahman is not grasped by the eye, nor by speech, nor by the other senses, nor by penance or good works. A man becomes pure through serenity of intellect; thereupon, in meditation, he beholds Him who is without parts. (Mundaka Upanishad 3.1.8)

Till the time you have slightest of desire/attachment to this world, you will keep taking birth endlessly.
To know, which is your last birth or what is your consciousness level, you need to introspect whether "Moksha" (liberation) is your ultimate goal of this life or not.

> Though grouped among the minor Upanishads, the Yoga-Kundalini Upanishad is a very important work on Kundalini Yoga. It begins with an analysis of the nature of Chitta. It maintains that Samskaras and Vasanas on the one hand, and Prana, on the other, constitute the causes for the existence of Chitta. If Vasanas are controlled, Prana is automatically controlled. If Prana is controlled, the Vasanas are automatically controlled.

http://www.yoga-age.com/modern/end.html

Thus, till the time you have desire, you will have re-birth.

The answer lies within you and only you are to chose.
Stay firm once you do make a choice.

> I am the Great Vak, Para-Shakti of the Universe. (Rig Veda.X.125.6-8)

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: The quotations of Vak-Sukta does not directly support your answer I think

Comment: It is a well known fact, that Kundalini is also refered by the name Para-Shakti. The knowledge of Chakras and its opening is also in the Vedas. I have definitely not invented it. Maharishi Vashisth had given this knowledge to Lord Rama and Lakshmana that any person can attain Moksha only by performing "Nishkaam Karm" i.e. giving up desires and attachment to the fruits of Karma. Same has been said by Lord Shri. Krishna in the Gita to Arjuna. It really does not require any reference as this knowledge is freely available in the Gita and is passed on to us via generations of ancesters.

Comment: The claim that Kundalini can be awakened and liberation attained at the will of the aspirant is not supported by your quotation.

Comment: Check the edit. The reference was only to describe Kundalini i.e. the term isnt my invention and is mentioned in the Rig Veda as Para-Shakti. I have added another Quote, which provides a way to reach the Brahman (God). Thus, the Upanishad states that one can reach the Brahman by "mediatation". In order to do that, one needs to have the will first to reach the Brahman i.e. to chose to meditate. It is not an assurance that Kundalini will definitely awaken via meditation, but it is one of the ways to do so. To become one with the Brahman is to get liberated from the cycle of life and death.

Comment: You might read here as well  http://www.yoga-age.com/modern/end.html